# Node V0.8.0 upgrade has issues in my project

Tags: node.js

I have upgraded my node to v0.8.0 which was previously v0.6.9. And I have upgraded my modules to the latest versions.

But when I start my server I am repeatedly getting an error like the following:

> Uncaught Exception: The \"sys\" module is now called \"util\"., stack:
>   Error: The \"sys\" module is now called \"util\".\n    at
>   sys.js:1:69\n    at NativeModule.compile (node.js:602:5)\n    at
>   Function.NativeModule.require (node.js:570:18)\n    at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:297:25)\n    at Module.require
>   (module.js:362:17)\n    at require (module.js:378:17)\n    at
>   Object.
>   (/home/user1/pollroll/code/web/node_modules/oauth-server/lib/util.js:23:7)\n
>   at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)\n    at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)\n    at Module.load
>   (module.js:356:32)"}

Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module [oauth-server](https://github.com/unscene/oauth-server) have been updated over a year ago. It's not ready to node.js 0.8 yet. You can resolve this issue manualy by changing `sys = require('sys')` to `sys = require('util')` in line 23 of `/home/user1/pollroll/code/web/node_modules/oauth-server/lib/util.js`.